# React router - Arbitrary nested path not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm tying to define my route in my React application logically but the URL contains an extra path nested (`/ecosystem`). The page renders but missing the `index.js, css, and fonts` for the nested pages - `/ecosystem/XXX`.
It works if I remove `/ecosystem` and I have `/XXX`.

I think React is unable to load the assets for `/ecosystem/XXX` since `/ecosystem` does not exist or define in the route.

Here is how my route looks like:

```
render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>

    <Route component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Dashboard}/>
      <Route path="/ecosystem/:name" component={Ecosystem}/>
      <Route path="*" component={Dashboard}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I would love to keep `/ecosystem` to have `/ecosystem/XXX` rather than `/XXX` but how can I ensure the assets get downloaded on the page for `/ecosystem/XXX`?

Comment: why not just nest `<Route path=":name">` *inside* `<Route path="ecosystem">`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans same issue, once I refresh the page - the css, fonts, index.js are not found

Comment: you may need to show more than just your router file: are you running this both server *and* client side?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I think is just client side

Comment: then yes, obviously this won't work. When you reload a page, you are asking a *server* for a resource hosted on a URL. No matter how much a client bundle can make you see nice URLs, if there is no server running with the same router file, then those URLs won't work "on their own". If you use path-based routing, rather than hash-based routing, you need to run both a client *and* a server on the same router configuration.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans you almost lost me there, am a React n00b, for server side, how would this be fixed?

Comment: you'll want to read some explanations of server-side rendering: basically you picked "path based routing": you have a bundle that the client loads, and then while you use that it makes it look like you're on different URLs, while in fact you're doing *nothing* with URLs. `history` just taps into the browser's history API to make it look that way. Nothing "real" is serving data on those URLs, so you need to write a server to do that if you want to load the URLs that your app fakes as URLs in their own right.

Comment: this isn't a React problem. the routes on your server (assuming Node/Express) need to match the routes of your client. If using server side rendering, route handlers for static files need to come before your React route handler